# Loop smoke created with physics in Blender Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

for my game I need a smoke animation which can be looped. I created the smoke in the physics tab and it looks really cool but I´m not able to find the perfect frame range which loops the smoke animation perfectly. Is there any easy way to do this? I have to add that I also have a wind element but this should blow consistently, am I right?

Would be great if someone could help me!

Thanks in advance!