# how make a loop candle flame

Tags: animation, looping

I put a fire animation on a candle (using quick efects), but when I put it in a loop, it goes off and on again because in the beginning of the animation it goes on, how do you keep it lit infinitely?

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail. An image/screen shot that shows what you have done would also be pretty helpful.

Comment: I don't think there's really a way to do this; the closest I can think of is taking some frames after the simulation gets started and blending the first and last together. Similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44132/599